# Adding DataFrame columns in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame that has a number of columns (about 20) containing string objects. I'm looking for a simple method to add all of the columns together into one new column, but have so far been unsuccessful e.g.:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[‘newcolumn’] = df[‘newcolumn’] + ‘/‘ + df.ix[:,i]
```

This results in an empty DataFrame column ‘newcolumn’ instead of the concatenated column.

I’m new to pandas, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you want the values of each column added together as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.apply(''.join, axis=1)
```